# Permission for a SharePoint document using MOSS web services

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, moss

We have a need to retrieve user groups which have read permissions for a document. We know the URL of the document. The following Permissions service provides the groups which has access, but it expects either a site URL or a list URL. We have a document URL. Is there any other service which provides permissions of a document. Or alternatively, is there a way to find out the list provided we know the document URL.

Permissions Service - `http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/permissions.asmx`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving item-level permissions is not possible with the out-of-the-box web services.

Einar Stangvik has developed a [custom web service that does this](http://einaros.blogspot.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html) and provides the source code. If you are able to deploy custom code to the server you can use it.

Comment: The source link in the blog you link to is dead. As a result, this answer is useless. (This is why link-only answers are discouraged.)

Comment: @Mogsdad The link to the blog still works which is what's important. I'm sure someone looking for the source code could contact Einar themselves and ask for it.

Comment: link pointing to is not at all related to this question or the answer