# Get Item Level Security using SharePoint WebServices

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2007

I am able to get the Permissions associated with a List or a Site using Permissions.GetPermissionCollection (ObjectName, ObjectType). The ObjectType parameter will accept either a Site or a List. Is there any way with the out-of-the-box webservices to get the Permissions associated with a ListItem?

I mean if I have NOT inherited the List permissions and have specified a set of specific permissions to a List Item or a document in a document Library then how can I get the permissions specified?

Comment: @Nagendra: Please note the etiquette of this site is to tick an answer if it has solved the problem described in a question. Please also upvote answers if they are relevant and helpful. These things encourage people to answer your questions. Also, if you tag your questions with `sharepoint` as well as the exact product (e.g. `moss-2007`) you will reach a wider audience. Thank you and welcome!

Comment: Thanks for that. Basically I am new to this site I will follow the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission for a SharePoint document using MOSS web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449845/permission-for-a-sharepoint-document-using-moss-web-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same as for documents. See the question [Permission for a SharePoint document using MOSS web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449845/permission-for-a-sharepoint-document-using-moss-web-services).

You cannot with the out-of-the-box web services but there is a [custom web service](http://einaros.blogspot.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html) available for free download and source code.

Comment: Sigh, what a pain in the ass.

Comment: The source link in the blog you link to is dead. As a result, this answer is useless. (This is why link-only answers are discouraged.)

Comment: @Mogsdad The alternative would have been to copy someone else's code into Stack Overflow. Is that encouraged?