# Modify ACL's on a file in Sharepoint server via web services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss, acl

Is there a way to do either of the following :

1)  Transfer an ACL entry on a file that is transferred to a Sharepoint server using the CopyIntoItems.asmx webservice in the Copy object?

OR

2)  Access a file/document in a Sharepoint List and add an ACL entry?

I am using the CopyIntoItems.asmx webservice to migrate a file into a Sharepoint Server, but it is not migrating an file-level ACL with it to the Sharepoint server. e.g.  domain\user (Read Only) access does not get transferred to the Sharepoint server.

I understand that Sharepoint mainly works with Sharepoint level permissions, but I want to know if there is a way to do what I described with administrator access to the sharepoint server

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because SharePoint does not 'know' your ACL's, it has it's own Security mechanism, SharePoint Groups, which in turn hold for instance an AD security group / user(s). The OOTB web servics do not allow for item level secuirty operations.

You would have to write your own code / webservice and deploy that to the sharepoint server, follow the link in the answer to this question  for more info on how to perform security operations on list items:

[Permission for a SharePoint document using MOSS web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449845/permission-for-a-sharepoint-document-using-moss-web-services)